# convertView.findViewById returning null even though convertView is not null

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display a ListView with different types of rows.
I have a `Result` abstract class inherited by `Artist`, `Label`, `Release` etc.
I'm getting results from a JSON response. Parsing is ok, my factory manages to create some `Result` objects properly.

Using these guides [1](http://antew.com/?p=162), [2](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296), I ended up extending `BaseAdapter`.

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String SEARCH_API_ENDPOINT = "http://xxxx.com/database/search?q=";

    SearchResultAdapter searchAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result_list);
        searchAdapter = new SearchResultAdapter();
        // handleIntent is needed because android:launchMode="singleTop" mode uses onNewIntent
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY); // get user input from search widget 
            String[][] params = new String[][]{{"q", query}}; // prepare GET parameters
            HttpRequestHandler requestHandler = new HttpRequestHandler("GET");
            String result;

            requestHandler.setURL(HttpRequestHandler.API_URL, HttpRequestHandler.SEARCH_QUERY_ENDPOINT);
            requestHandler.addParameters(params);
            result = requestHandler.sendRequest();
            if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    ArrayList<Result> resultList = new ResultFactory(new JSONObject(result)).getResults(); // JSON to Result objects
                    for (Result res: resultList) {
                        searchAdapter.addItem(res);
                    }
                    setListAdapter(searchAdapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("xxjsonexception");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class SearchResultAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<Result> searchResults = new ArrayList<Result>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public SearchResultAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void addItem(Result result) {
            searchResults.add(result);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return searchResults.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return searchResults.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return Result.Type.values().length; // enum length
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return searchResults.get(position).getType().ordinal();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Result tmp = searchResults.get(position); // only for testing
            System.out.println("xxItem type " + tmp.getType());
            View v = searchResults.get(position).getView(mInflater, convertView);
            if (v == null) {
                System.out.println("xxgetviewnull");
            } else {
                System.out.println("xxgetviewok");
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Result.java :

```
public abstract class Result {
    // general search result class

    public enum Type {
        ARTIST,
        RELEASE,
        MASTER,
        LABEL,
        ERROR,
    }

    public static final String NODE_RESULTS = "results";
    public static final String NODE_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String NODE_THUMB = "thumb";
    public static final String NODE_RESSOURCE = "resource_url";
    public static final String NODE_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String NODE_URI = "uri";
    public static final String NODE_ID = "id";

    public static final String TYPE_ARTIST = "artist";
    public static final String TYPE_RELEASE = "release";
    public static final String TYPE_MASTER = "master";
    public static final String TYPE_LABEL = "label";


    protected String thumb;
    protected String title;
    protected String ressource_url;
    protected static Type type;
    protected String uri;
    protected int id;


    public void setData(JSONObject jsonResult) {
        try {
            setId(jsonResult.getInt(Result.NODE_ID));
            setUri(jsonResult.getString(Result.NODE_URI));
            setRessource_url(jsonResult.getString(Result.NODE_RESSOURCE));
            setThumb(jsonResult.getString(Result.NODE_THUMB));
            setTitle(jsonResult.getString(Result.NODE_TITLE));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            type = Type.ERROR;
        }
    }

    // getters and setters ..

    public abstract View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView);
}
```

Artist.java :

```
public class Artist extends Result{

    public Artist(){
        type = Type.ARTIST;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_artist, null);
        }
        TextView textTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_artist);
        if (textTitle == null) {
            System.out.println("xxtexttitle null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("xxtexttitleok " + title);
        }
        textTitle.setText(title);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Label.java

```
public class Label extends Result {

    public Label() {
        type = Type.LABEL;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_label, null);
        }
        if (convertView == null) {
            System.out.println("xxconvertviewisnull");
        } else {
            System.out.println("xxconvertviewok");
        }
        TextView titleText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_label);
        titleText.setText(title);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

As you can see, my `Artist` and `Label` class are very similar but only my `Label` class throws a NPE at `TextView titleText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_label)`.

This is not a `setContentView()` as I am doing it in `onCreate`.
My `Result` objects are never `null` nor do they have `null` fields.
I do check to see if `convertView` is `null` in my `getView` methods, inflating a View if ever it is `null`.
I am not using a ViewHolder because `Release` and `Master` will be displaying extra fields.

EDIT :

list_item_label.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title_label"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item_artist.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title_artist"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#FFAAAA"
              android:textSize="14pt"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your convertView is a "list_item_artist" view when you reach a Label object in your list. Then convertview isnt null, but the wrong type of view which cant find the title_label.

Reverse the list order and you get a null pointer with a artist view instead.

Comment: Ah! This definitely makes sense. I added `if (convertView.getId() != R.id.list_item_artist) { convertView = inflater.inflate(R.id.list_item_artist, null); }` and it is working now.  
Do you know if there is any way I can handle this more efficiently? I'm pretty sure inflating every time the `convertView` has a different view is not very good.

Comment: Hmm the way I usually do it is just having the same (convert)view, but then hiding or toggling the views in the layout depending on the object type.

(So i would have both textviews in the same xml file)

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid but I guess it's still better than inflating over and over. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the list_item_layout doesn't have an element with an id of title_label, which would cause the `convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_label)` to return null and then throw a NullPointerException at `titleText.setText(title)`. It will build just fine if there is another layout that contains an id of title_lable, but then throw the NPE at runtime.

Comment: this is not the case. I have updated my post to add my xml files.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Have you cleaned and rebuilt the project recently? If not I would give that a shot. Also, I would move the block 2 lines of code proceeding the else block, into the else block. If convertView == null evaluates true, you will always throw a NPE.

Comment: I already have tried rebuilding the project. The second `convertView == null` part was only to check if it was properly inflated (it is).